# How to create a xml document and fill data from json object

Tags: c#, xml

I have a existing xml file. format is as below:

```
<Item>
<a>3</a>
<b>Wild</b>
<ISOCntry>c</ISOCntry>
<ISOLang>eng</ISOLang>
<City>Malone</City>
<Media>
<StrmRel>99</StrmRel>
<StrmBndwid>36</StrmBndwid>
</Item>
```

And one json file.Now i had created a json object out of json file.
But now how should i create a similar xml as of sample xml and fill data from json object.

Comment: How does your `JSON` object look like and what have you tried to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize JSON and get object that you can then serialize again to get xml.

You can use this method for serialization:

```
    public static string SerializeObject(object value)
    {
        if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
            return value.ToString();

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new
              DataContractSerializer(value.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, value);
        }

        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
```